# Adding to an object through a function

Tags: javascript, object

I am currently trying to add to an object through a function.

My code is:

```
var ob = {};

function add(f, fun) {
    ob[f] = fun();
}

add('hi', function() {
    alert('hello')
})

ob.hi()​
```

So this is suppose to change ob to:

```
var ob = {
     hi: function(){
      alert('hello')
     }
}
```

It does alert `hello` but just from the triggering of the add function (which I want to stop) and not from the `ob.hi()` function.

Thanks for any help. If you want you can also check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/r6ZXy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the function and assigning its return value to the property. You need to assign a reference to the function to the property instead. Change your `add` function:

```
function add(f, fun) {
    ob[f] = fun; //No invoking parentheses!
}
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/r6ZXy/1/).

If you look at the console in your original fiddle you get a hint of what's going wrong:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'hi' of object `#<Object>` is not a
>   function

Comment: You helped big, since now I finally fixed an issue I had with the library im building

Answer (score 1):

Add your function as a property of your object :

```
ob['hi'] = function() {
    alert('hello')
};
```

or

```
ob[funname] = fun;
```

if the function was defined elsewhere.

Don't write a `add` function just to set a property. Replacing a standard feature of the language by a custom setter isn't going to make the code more readable.

And don't forget that you can define classes in javascript :

```
function Rect(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

Rect.prototype.contains = function(x, y) {
    return x>=this.x && x<=this.x+this.w && y>=this.y && y<=this.y+this.h;
};
```

All objects created as `new Rect(0, 1, 2, 3)` have the `contains` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I will need to set more than one property and I will want to do this with a function

Comment: Apart for homework, I don't see a reason to use a function to replace a standard feature of the language. If you're building a library, follow best practices.